# Problems with createObjectURL

Tags: php, javascript

I have trouble with createObjectURL function when it comes to safari. So my idea was to do this in php and return the value back to the script. It will be a "fallback" function because for other browsers I use this createObjectURL.

My question is simple. What function I use in PHP to create the same result as I would have got if I used other browsers?

I tried base64_deode, not working.

Anyway. Need a workaround for Safari

Comment: You mean you want to read the user-agent in PHP and echo a JS createObjectURL if it's safari?

Comment: @rath I uploading images. Each file data is converted with createObjectURL in JS, but not working in Safari. As a fallback I was thinking to send a ajax call to .php with the file data and convert it in PHP to blob, and send it back with a response to Javascript, if browser not support that function. The response result should be the same as the result you would get with a native createObjectURL function in JS